# Share object between different file nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have trouble sharing an object between app.js and an imported file.

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = require('./lib/express');

var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sql = require('./lib/sqlRequete');
var app = express();

// Init database
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'master2i'
});
connection.connect();

app.post('/ajaxRequete', urlencodedParser, function(req,res){
    sql.formerSql(req.body);
});

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("Le serveur est lancé et écoute sur le port "+port);
});
```

**sqlRequete.js**

```
'use strict';

var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.formerSql=function(req){

  var SQL;

  switch(req.action){
    case 'login':
      SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE pseudo ='" + req.pseudo + "' AND pass = '" + req.psw + "'";
      this.executeSql(SQL,'SELECT');
      break;
  }
}

exports.executeSql=function(requete, type){

  switch(type){

    case 'SELECT':
      connection.query(requete, function(err,rows,fields){
         if (err){
          throw err;
        }else{
          console.log('The solution is: ',rows);
        }
      });
      break;
  }
}
```

**sqlRequete.js** cannot access variable and object from **app.js**.
As an example, I can't access `connection`
What are the solutions ? How should I structure my code ?

Comment: What about add `init` function at `sqlRequete.js` module and pass any objects?

Comment: This would work in this case because connection will not change. But if I have variable or object wich there values are changing in app.js, they will be deprecated on sqlRequete.js, didn't they ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass objects from `app.js` to `sqlRequete.js` file by the following way.

**sqlRequete.js**

```
module.exports = function(connection){
   function formerSql(req){
     var SQL;
     switch(req.action){
        case 'login':
          SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE pseudo ='" + req.pseudo + "' AND pass = '" + req.psw + "'";
          this.executeSql(SQL,'SELECT');
          break;
     }
   }

   function executeSql(requete, type){
     switch(type){
       case 'SELECT':
          connection.query(requete, function(err,rows,fields){
          if (err){
            throw err;
          }else{
            console.log('The solution is: ',rows);
          }
       });
       break;
     }
   }  
   return { 
      formerSql : formerSql,
      executeSql : executeSql
   }
}
```

And in **app.js**, pass the connection object

```
 var mysql      = require('mysql');
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
   password : '',
   database : 'master2i'
 });
 connection.connect();
 var sql = require('./lib/sqlRequete')(connection);
```

Comment: Thanks. Will the connection object be always up-to-date or saved at the time of the require call ?

Comment: Sorry about the typo. I wrote the code in this browser and mistakenly skipped the `function` keyword.

Comment: Yes, it should. You should try it.

Comment: I fastly tried it, and it is only copying the value at the time of the require call. Howewer, it is still a good solution for a const object I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you'll be using a third file (in your case scenario).

A resulting folder structure like this:

```
- index.js
- lib/
|__ orm.js
|__ app.js
|__ sqlRequete.js
```

Where the `orm.js` file is creating the connection an returning the instance:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
module.exports = function () {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'master2i'
    });
    connection.connect();

    // IMPORTANT
    // here is where you're sharing variables between files!
    return connection;
}
```

**However, specifically for your example,** I'd simply move the initialisation of the SQL instance to the `sqlRequete.js` file.

```
exports.start = function () {
    // Init database
    var mysql      = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'master2i'
    });
    connection.connect();
}
```

And request it on the `app.js`:

```
var app = express();

sql.start();
```